# Why do I get an error running sudo `apt-get update`?

Tags: apt, package-management, lubuntu, sudo, nodejs

Install Lubuntu 16.04 Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update`,
I get the following error:

```
W: The repository «cdrom: // Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20170216) xenial Release» does not have a Publication file.
N: Data from a repository like this can not be authenticated and therefore its use is potentially dangerous.
N: See the apt-secure (8) man page for details on creating repositories and configuring users.
W: The repository «http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial Release» does not have a Publication file.
N: Data from a repository like this can not be authenticated and therefore its use is potentially dangerous.
N: See the apt-secure (8) man page for details on creating repositories and configuring users.
E: Failed to get cdrom: // Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20170216) / dists / xenial / main / binary-i386 / Packages Use «apt-cdrom» to make APT recognize this CD. You can not use «apt-get update» to add new CDs
E: Failed to obtain http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found
E: Some index files could not be downloaded, have been omitted, or old ones used instead.
I have run apt-cdrom as it says, but nothing happens.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I have tried to install Node.js and it also gave me error:
          npm update check failed │
│ Try running with sudo or get access │
│ to the local update config store via │
│ sudo chown -R $ USER: $ (id -gn $ USER) /home/miguel/.config
```

Try cleaning the cache, but the command did not work with the command sudo npm cache clean -f
I do not know what else I can do to correct errors.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm ignoring the cdrom not inserted (*its a warning "W:" & not error*), but the PPA does not support xenial [16.04] (http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/) but only releases 9.10 thru 14.10 (utopic).  You need to remove that PPA as it does you no good anyway without 16.04 Xenial support.  I'd also comment out the cd-rom (your install media) but putting a "#" at the start of its line.

Comment: Thanks guiverc, I'm not sure what I should do to eliminate PPA and comment on CDROM

Comment: For the PPA - I'll point you to https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed and for the 'cdrom' I'd suggest you edit the file & place a "#" at the start of the line making the line a comment, use something like `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` to edit it, substituting `vim` with whatever [text] editor you prefer.  (*I suggest commenting out, as it's easy to undo this by editing the file again.. if for some reason you want it back...*)

Comment: Thank you very much @guiverc, if you put it in response, I will accept you with pleasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "W:" is a warning you can ignore, telling you only the cdrom (or install media) is not present. You can remove or comment this out (*I suggest commenting it out as it allows restoration if you make a mistake, or need it for some reason in the future*) using

`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

and putting a "#" at the start of the line. The line will become a comment which means it's ignored by the system.  (*you can also use another text editor instead of `vim` but just using it in-lieu of vim*)

The PPA you list I looked at (via http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/) and can see it covers releases 9.10 thru 14.10 and thus not 16.04 (Xenial). Thus it's of no use to you and should be removed.  I'll refer you to another page for how to remove

[How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: try `grep -r cdrom /etc/apt/*`  which means 'grep' (search files for specified string) all files in /etc/apt/ and subdirectories (because of the -r) looking for "cdrom").  they'll print out in format "/path/filename:line_contents" *telling you what file (before the ':') and show the line*